# Log4J scanning fails to create csv file

Tags: powershell, log4j, log4j2, powershell-remoting

```
invoke-command -scriptblock {powershell -File "D:\batch\Fix-4Log4J.ps1"} -computer $Server -AsJob -JobName "Scan4Log4J" -Verbose -EA SilentlyContinue
```

**When I run this script locally, with enter-pssession the script works just fine but NO CSV**

```
& D:\batch\Fix-4Log4J.ps1
```

**Yet every time I try to invoke, directly or with SAPS it fails to create file**

SYNTAX of EXE:

```
.\log4j2-scan.exe --force-fix d:\apps c:\users --report-csv --throttle 45
```

Now go and run it with NO other choices....

Comment: Note that you don't need to call `powershell.exe` in your remote script block - `& "D:\batch\Fix-4Log4J.ps1"` will do. Aside from that, while it's commendable that you shared a solution to your problem, your problem isn't entirely clear,  and neither is your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...and oh my goodness, I figured it out... :)

> `invoke-command -scriptblock {powershell -File "D:\batch\Fix-4Log4J.ps1"} -computer $Server -AsJob -JobName "Scan4Log4J" -Verbose -EA SilentlyContinue **get-job -name Scan4Log4J| receive-job -wait**`

It was the receive-job that showed WHERE that BLASTED log went! HAH!

```
.\log\20220909.txt
```

WHEW!!!

Comment: **As you create the scan job, copy the PS script to every server -scan with this syntax:**  
//
if(test-path d:\apps\){cd d:\batch\output; d:\batch\log4j2-scan.exe --force-fix cd\apps --report-csv --throttle 2000}
//
#..etc#

**Notice you HAVE to cd to the folder you want to create the log in? The app is buggy...**